# How to compare Dates in MarkLogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am having below XML in $doc variable

```
 let $doc := <root>
              <date>12/31/2016</date>
             </root>
```

I want to take this date and compare it with Today's date. It should return me True but it is returning me false.

I am using the below code-

```
let $doc := <root>
              <date>12/31/2016</date>
             </root>


let $date := $doc/date/text()
let $today :=fn:format-date(fn:current-date(),"[M01]/[D01]/[Y0001]")
return $date le $today
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast the date string as an xs:date to be able to compare them this way. Formatting using `fn:format-date()` just produces a string while `fn:current-date()` returns an xs:date. This snippet accomplishes what you want, but you might want to also consider persisting data in your doc in the xs:date format, ie `<date>2016-12-31</date>`.

```
let $doc := 
    <root>
        <date>12/31/2016</date>
    </root>
let $date-string := $doc/date/text()
let $date-parts := fn:tokenize($date-string,"/")

(: rearrange date parts into yyyy-mm-dd string and cast as xs:date :)
let $date := xs:date(fn:concat($date-parts[3],"-",$date-parts[1],"-",$date-parts[2]))

let $today := fn:current-date()

return $date le $today

=> false
```

If the date is persisted in the xs:date format, it could be simplified like this:

```
let $doc := 
    <root>
        <date>2016-12-31</date>
    </root>

return xs:date($doc/date/text()) le fn:current-date()
```

You can also then use a range index on the date element to leverage `cts:element-range-query()` to select documents that meet your desired criteria, etc. when the date is persisted this way.

Comment: xdmp:parse-dateTime as suggested by Daldei works too, but most useful with textual months (Dec/31/2016). Dates like these are easy to normalize with string manipulation. The following library is capable of handling many odd date formats, taking you some trouble out of your hands: https://github.com/grtjn/ml-datetime

Answer (score 2):

What you have done in your code is created 2 xs:string variables then comparing them lexicaly.   ( e.g. "12/31/2016"  compare to 'mm/dd/yyyy' )
This will compare according to the locale as string compares not date compares.
There are only a few formats which compare lexicaly the same as by typed date value, the xs:date is one of those, its format is YYYY-MM-DD which has the property of being comparable lexicaly as well as by typed date.
In general its preferable to not rely on that and instead convert to xs:date or xs:dateTime and compare by dateTime value -- The procedure is the same, you need to coerce these text values into the standard date form either by using the xdmp:parse-dateTime() or similar functions given the format at hand, or by parsing the text format and producing the format xs:date() wants.   Then compare the 2 typed date values.

https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:parse-dateTime

Comment: DALDEI- Thank you for clarification :) I understood the concept now.

Answer (score 1):

I used the below approach-

```
let $doc := <root>
          <date>12/31/2016</date>
         </root>


let $date := fn:format-date(xs:date(xdmp:parse-dateTime([Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]",$doc/date/text())),"[Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]")
let $today := fn:format-date(fn:current-date(),"[Y0001]/[M01]/[D01]")
return $date le $today
```

Comment: The above will work equally well if you take out the format-date calls. You can compare xs:date directly.

Comment: grtjn-Thanks :)